# glance error: pathspec 'requirements.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: openstack, grizzly, devstack

I am trying to install `Openstack Grizzly using DevStack` but getting following error. look like something related to `glance`

```
2013-10-11 12:24:46 + sudo chown -R stack /opt/stack/glance/glance.egg-info
2013-10-11 12:24:46 + '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
2013-10-11 12:24:46 + cd /opt/stack/glance
2013-10-11 12:24:46 + git checkout -- requirements.txt test-requirements.txt setup.py
2013-10-11 12:24:46 error: pathspec 'requirements.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git.
2013-10-11 12:24:46 error: pathspec 'test-requirements.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git.
2013-10-11 12:24:46 ++ failed
2013-10-11 12:24:46 ++ local r=1
2013-10-11 12:24:46 +++ jobs -p
2013-10-11 12:24:46 ++ kill
2013-10-11 12:24:46 ++ set +o xtrace
2013-10-11 12:24:46 stack.sh failed: full log in /opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log.2013-10-11-122421
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem solved :)

Ran following command in devstack directory (devstack git directory)

```
git checkout stable/grizzly
```